# MySQL - Pythonanywhere - Adding 2 values at the same time

Tags: mysql, pythonanywhere

I am using this code for a database:

```
    class Wachtwoord(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "wachtwoorden"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    pogingen = db.Column(db.String(80))
    namen = db.Column(db.String(80))

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])

def main():

    if request.method == "GET":
        print("in request.method = get")
        return render_template("main_page.html")

    if (request.form["Knop1"] == "1912"):
        print ('Het wachtwoord is geraden:', request.form["Knop1"])
        poging = Wachtwoord(pogingen=request.form["Knop1"])
        naam = Wachtwoord(namen=request.form["Knop2"])
        db.session.add(poging)
        db.session.add(naam)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect("http://tegelizr.nl/tegeltjes/dat-klopt-als-een-bus.png")

    else:
        print ('Iemand heeft een het wachtwoord geraden:', request.form["Knop1"])
        poging = Wachtwoord(pogingen=request.form["Knop1"])
        naam = Wachtwoord(namen=request.form["Knop2"])
        db.session.add(poging, naam)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template("main_page.html")
```

When I use this code and I do "select * from wachtwoorden;", it returns this:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/e83343d29e65b754bce97fd36a8248e3.png]

So it returns: pogingen-null and then next line null-namen. How can I make it pogingen-namen, without the "null". I added db.session.commit() after db.session.add() so why doesn't it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have this:

```
    poging = Wachtwoord(pogingen=request.form["Knop1"])
    naam = Wachtwoord(namen=request.form["Knop2"])
    db.session.add(poging)
    db.session.add(naam)
```

That means you're telling the system to create two new `Wachtwoord` objects, one of which has `pogingen` set to `request.form["Knop1"]`, and `namen` unset, and the other has `namen` set to `request.form["Knop2"]`, and `pogingen` unset.

So the answer to why it's creating two rows in the database is that you're telling it to do that :-)

To create a single `Wachtwoord` with the two values set on it, just do this:

```
    wachtwoord = Wachtwoord(pogingen=request.form["Knop1"], namen=request.form["Knop2"])
    db.session.add(wachtwoord)
```

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks a lot! :)